# Set Opsworks Deployment recipes personalized for multiple apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks, cookbook

I have the standard PHP layer in OpsWorks Stack.

There are two application on this layer:

- app1, on the domain app1.mydomain.com
- app2, on the domain app2.mydomain.com

The applications run on the same servers.

I have a git repo with my deployment recipes. Everything works fine.

But now I need to personalize the deployment recipes for each app.

For example:

- i need that the folder 'folder_1' of the app 'app1' is writable 777
- i need that the folder 'folder_1' of the app 'app2' is readable 644

Now, I have only the recipe that runs in all the deployed apps. How can i personalize my deployment recipe to run in different ways for different apps?

Thank you in advance

Edit: here what i'd like to do:

```
node[:deploy].each do |app_name, deploy|                                                                                                      

  [IF APPLICATION ONE (how can i grab application variable?)]:
  script "change_permissions" do                                       
    interpreter "bash"                                                 
    user "root"                                                        
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"                                
    code <<-EOH                                                        
    chmod -R 777 uploads
    mv .htaccess_production .htaccess                                  
    EOH                                                                
  end

  [ELSE IF APPLICATION 2]:
  script "change_permissions" do                                       
    interpreter "bash"                                                 
    user "root"                                                        
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"                                
    code <<-EOH                                                        
    chmod -R 755 uploads
    rm .htaccess_production
    EOH                                                                
  end                                                                    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two apps settings to apply, try make one as default setup and use either a chef tag or node attribute to do a switch case. I also had experience using environment variable to differentiate the route for implementation but that may not be necessary if the change is local on an instance.

Now if the change involved is significant, you should consider to place them in separate recipes and run individual one in the switch case block. It is easier to maintain later on. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, i want to proceed in this way. but i don't know how to take a specific variable to recognize which app i am deploying and then i don't know how to implement an "if" statement for chef.. can you show me the simplest example please?

Comment: Do you have any cookbook attribute that specify the installation directory? This is one way to figure out which app you are deploying. Without much context, it's difficult to give example.

Comment: i think i can specify attributes through json environment variables. but then, how do i use the variables? I added the general script for the apps. Sorry for my low experience with chef cookbooks and thanks in advance